# facing trouble while using jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery

im stuck in Jqueryajax although it works but it doesn't check all my if condition. 
here is my code where i use jQueryAjax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //data: 'user= ' + user + ' &pwd= ' + pwd,
    url: "jsp/admin/master/Connectteacher.jsp?tuser="+tuser+"&tpwd="+tpwd,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function( check ) {

       if ( $.trim( check ) == 'new' ) {
           window.location.replace("jsp/admin/master/Newuser.jsp?name="+tuser);
       }
       if ( $.trim( check ) == 'proceed') {  
           window.location.replace("jsp/admin/master/teacher-profile.jsp");
       }
       if ( $.trim( check ) == 'block') {
           $('#teacherError').html("You are blocked!");
       }
       if ( $.trim( check ) == 'incorrect') {
           $('#teacherError').html("Incorrect username or password");
       }

    }, error: function() {        
       $('#teacherError').html("database not connected");
    }

});
```

and here is my Connectteacher.jsp:

```
LoginTeacher l = new LoginTeacher();
String i = l.teacherAuthentication(request.getParameter("tuser"), request.getParameter("tpwd"));

char chusr = i.charAt(1);
char atmpts = i.charAt(0);
int at = Character.getNumericValue( atmpts );
System.out.println("matters" + at);

if( chusr == 'T' && at < 4 ) {
   out.print("new");
}
if( chusr == 'F' && at < 4 ) {
   System.out.println("inside old");
   out.print("proceed");
}
if( at > 3 ) {
  out.print("block");
}
//if(chusr==' ')
//{
  //out.print("incorrect");
//}
```

it works fine for the first 3 if condition but not when i include the fourth one. is there any restriction that we can use only limited if condition inside jQueryAjax. please help me

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println("matters"+at);` line will be in your output also, making none of your conditions possible.

Also, using something like Firebug will help you determine exactly what the server is sending back.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery code . I think it will work  ..Iam not in jsp now , You need to encode the output data using any data-interchange format such as json , html or any other

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"user": user ,"pwd": pwd },
    url: "jsp/admin/master/Connectteacher.jsp,
    cache: false,
    success: function(check) {  

        if (check == "new") {
            window.location.replace("jsp/admin/master/Newuser.jsp?name="+tuser);
          }
       if (check == "proceed") {  
           window.location.replace("jsp/admin/master/teacher-profile.jsp");
       }
       if (check == "block") {
                $('#teacherError').html("You are blocked!");
                 }
       if (check == "incorrect") {
                $('#teacherError').html("Incorrect username or password");
                  }
        },
    error: function() {        
       //Statements for handling ajax errors (eg . checking request response)               
}

});
```

Comment: You are missing a `"` and the parameters are `tuser` and `tpwd` not `user` and `pwd`. You should explain what you changed and why you think it should work, e.g. why you removed the `$.trim` or why you choose `data` over adding it directly as paramter to the url. (It is not always clear for everyone from the first look what change din the code and why)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if string empty or null for that check below methods

Method 1:

```
if (chusr != null && chusr != '') {
// Your Code Here
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (chusr.length != 0 && chusr != '') {
// Your Code Here
}
```